# Angular Alert Service needs advice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I am new to angular but I am lost on where I need to put my AlertService and module import stuff.
For now I import it in my core module. My core module is imported in my app module.
The alert service works well in my app.component.html
But I can't make it work in my home module. My HomeModule is imported in the appModule too.
In order here my AlertModule def:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonModule],
 declarations: [AlertComponent],
 exports: [AlertComponent]
})
export class AlertModule { }
```

Here my core module def:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent, 
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AlertModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NavbarService
  ],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [
    FooterComponent, 
    HeaderComponent,
    AlertComponent
    ]
  })
  export class CoreModule extends EnsureImportedOnceModule  {
    public constructor(@SkipSelf() @Optional() parent: CoreModule){
      super(parent);
  }

}
```

Here my app module def:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   CoreModule,
   SharedModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   HomeModule
 ],
declarations: [
   AppComponent
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
exports: [      
 ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I got the ERROR in app/modules/home/home.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'alert' is not a known element:

Any advice on how to use AlertModule correctly in my project structure?

Comment: You are writing about an AlertService, but you are exporting an AlarmComponent. Which one is it?

Comment: My AlertService is part on a alertModule that contain, model, service and component to display alert. This alertModule is imported in the CoreModule then AppModule. I was expexting to be able to use AletService AND ComponementService anywhere in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import `CoreModule` in `HomeModule`.

Comment: AlertModule (that contain AlertService, AlertComponent, AlertModel) are imported in my CORE module, not the shared one. Maybe I do it wrong? Maybe I need to split up the AlertModule to let the AlertService in my core module then use it by Provider, and the AlertModel et AlertComponent in the sharedModule?

Comment: In order to use any service, component, model in core module, you will need to import it in the module you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a component from an other module, you need to export that component in the module and import the module in the one using it. In this case, to solve your error, import the alertModule in your homeModule.
I don't know why you export your alertComponent again in your coreModule though.

If you need your alertService everywhere in your app, use provideIn: 'root' in your service or declare it in your core module as a provider.